# jQuery Autocomplete PHP Mysql posting different field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I am making use of jQuery's Autocomplete where I am populating my autocomplete dropdown with a php file called site.php. Site.php gets the values from a mysql table called site and which has 3 columns: `id`, `code` and `site`. I want my autocomplete to show only `code` and `site` and then store the corresponding `id` in my other table.

Everything works fine except that autocomplete is posting the `code` and the `site` selected but not the `id`. What do I need to change in order to send the `id` to my php POST and not `code` and `site`? Scripts as follows:

PHP file: site.php

```
<?php
        $server = 'sql203.com';
        $user = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $password = 'xxxxxxx';
        $database = 'b17';
    $mysqli = new MySQLi($server,$user,$password,$database);
    /* Connect to database and set charset to UTF-8 */
    if($mysqli->connect_error) {
      echo 'Database connection failed...' . 'Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ' ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
      exit;
    } else {
      $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    }
    /* retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends */
    $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
    $a_json = array();
    $a_json_row = array();
    if ($data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `b17_16413362_upupa`.`site` WHERE code LIKE '%$term%' OR site LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY code , site")) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
            $id = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
            $code = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['code']));
            $site = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['site']));

            $a_json_row["id"] = $id;
            $a_json_row["value"] = $code.' '.$site;
            $a_json_row["label"] = $code.' '.$site;
            array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
        }
    }
    // jQuery wants JSON data

    echo json_encode($a_json);
    flush();

    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $("#sitex").autocomplete({
    source: 'site.php',
     minLength: 0
        }).focus(function(){     

             $(this).autocomplete("search");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP, change

```
$a_json_row["value"] = $code.' '.$site;
```

to

```
$a_json_row["value"] = $id;
```

The 'value' property is the data that will be submitted by the form. The 'label' property is what will be displayed to the user.

Comment: when I do that it posts the `id` correctly BUT when the user clicks on the autocomplete choice it shows the `id` only instead of `code` and `site` ...